# Can wget download file from ftp site when url path and ftp path are different?

Tags: ftp, wget, mirroring

I have a website like `www.mysite.com`

When I login to my site with `FTP client`, my root folder is: `/home/domains`

And my site files are located at `/home/domains/mysite.com/public_html/`

There are too many web sites under `/home/domains like /home/domains/myothersite`

But I am unable to download my file via wget.

If I use this command below, it downloads ALL SITES on my server.

```
wget.exe --mirror --ftp-user=XXX --ftp-password=XXX ftp://my.ip.add.ress
```

I also tried `-directory-prefix=/home/domains/mysite.com/public_html/` but it didn't work.

Can I download file from ftp site when url path and ftp path are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wget like this;

wget -m ftp://username:password@www.mydomain.tld/public_html

:)

Answer (score 1):

This is my own answer :)

```
wget --mirror -r --no-parent ftp://username:password@www.mydomain.tld/public_html/
```

It worked for me

Comment: /public_html is my path on FTP site